# How to fix this error when launching texindy in windows using TeXstudio editor?

Tags: indexing, texstudio, xindy

I noticed that recently, when I launch `texindy` using the shortkey in TeXstudio <kbd>F12</kbd> it throws an error:

```
Process started: texindy.exe

usage: texindy.pl [-V?h] [-qv] [-iglr] [-d magic] [-o outfile.ind] [-t log] \ [-L lang] [-C codepage] [-M module] [-I input] [idx0 idx1 ...] GNU-STYLE LONG OPTIONS FOR SHORT OPTIONS: -V / --version -? / -h / --help -q / --quiet -v / --verbose -i / --stdin -g / --german -l / --letter-ordering -r / --no-ranges -d / --debug (multiple times) (supported: script, keep_tmpfiles, markup, level=n) -o / --out-file -t / --log-file -L / --language -C / --codepage -M / --module (multiple times) -I / --input-markup (supported: latex, omega) C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: command failed with exit code 1: perl.exe c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/xindy/texindy.pl

Process exited with error(s)
```

Below is a screenshot of texindy configuration in TeXstudio:
[image]

When I use `arara` to compile there is no problem with `xindy`, here is the `arara` code:

```
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }   
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
```

This is an excerpt from `arara` log file.txt regarding `xindy`:

```
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
xindy  -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "phdmain" -t "phdmain.glg" -o "phdmain.gls" "phdmain.glo"
Opening logfile "phdmain.glg" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "iaheC42kMp"...
Loading module "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy"...
Loading module "lang/english/utf8.xdy"...
Finished loading module "lang/english/utf8.xdy".
Finished loading module "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy".
Loading module "phdmain.xdy"...
Loading module "tex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex.xdy".
Finished loading module "phdmain.xdy".
Finished loading module "iaheC42kMp".
Finished reading indexstyle.
Finalizing indexstyle... (done)
```

This is an excerpt from the running messages while compiling the document successfully using `arara`:

```
Status: SUCCESS

Running MakeGlossaries...

makeglossaries version 2.07 (2013-06-17)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
xindy  -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "phdmain" -t "phdmain.glg" -o "phdmain.gls" "phdmain.glo"

Opening logfile "phdmain.glg" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "iaheC42kMp"...
Loading module "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy"...
Loading module "lang/english/utf8.xdy"...
Finished loading module "lang/english/utf8.xdy".
Finished loading module "lang/english/utf8-lang.xdy".
Loading module "phdmain.xdy"...
Loading module "tex.xdy"...
Finished loading module "tex.xdy".
Finished loading module "phdmain.xdy".
Finished loading module "iaheC42kMp".
Finished reading indexstyle.
Finalizing indexstyle... (done)

Reading raw-index "oxOB1i9YoU"...
Finished reading raw-index.

Processing index... [10%] [20%] [30%] [40%] [50%] [60%] [70%] [80%] [90%] [100%]
Finished processing index.
```

But as I said when I invoke `xindy` alone it throws the error mentioned in the beginning of the question.

**So what am I missing here? how to fix this error?**

Note:
TeXstudio version: 2.6.4
Xindy version: 2.4
Distribution TexLive2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you did not show the relevant screenshot, I am quite sure the issue is a change sometimes occurring for unknown reasons. At least this happened here in a portable TeXstudio, and a user in Germen usenet group `de.comp.text.tex` complained about this, too:

In menu “Options” —> "Configure TeXstudio” —> “Commands” the entry for Texindy lacked the parameter. Therefore changing this to

`texindy.exe %.idx`

should bring the function back to you.

Cf. a screenshot made by Harish Kumar for another question ([Has anyone managed to use \glossaries with TeXstudio on Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156270/), because of this `makeglossaries.exe` is marked):

[image: screenshot of TeXstudio configuration]

You should control the marked `makeglossaries.exe`, as well, because this was also affected by this strange phenomenon/bug.

---

Harish and me have BTW compared our versions (“About TeXstudio”) and we seem to have the same, but he has the installation variant and I as said above the portable one.

Comment: +1, for the careful answer, indeed, fixed the problem. My guess this would also fix a strange behavior that I used to live with, that gls{} sometimes does not abbreviate the acronym but would typeset as if *firstly* used, so I had to pass glstext{} to force that.